# How can i copy shared folder files into local machine using angularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, swing

I have created a tool in swing(JAVA) by using which i am copying files from shared location into a local system. I wan't to do the same in AngularJS is there any way by which i can copy files from one location to another. The shared folder location and local machine location is provided by user. I just have to fetch location's from textfield and perform copy paste operation.

CODE what i have written in swing:
`

```
void copyPaste(String l,String m )
{
    File srcDir = new File(l);
    File destDir = new File(m);
    try {           
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                System.exit(1);

    }

}`
```

How can i do the same in AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't support client side file manipulation for security reasons.

the  [File and Directory Entries API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Introduction) is non standard and allow you to manipulate a sandoboxed file system (you cannot write file to an arbitrary folder)

If you want to stick to javascript you can replicate that code on the server side  with NodeJS (e.g. [this](https://github.com/AvianFlu/ncp) module)